# Flash 11 and Stage3D for vector rendering?

Tags: flash, vector, rendering, gpu, stage3d

I have a flash application that relies heavily on the native flash renderer (mainly vector drawing with a bunch of lineto, curveto commands).

Most of the demos and benchmarks I've seen are just resizing/rotating sprites. Will the new 3d engine improve performance on an application that mainly does vector rendering?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to render vector art to bitmaps, either at design or run time. You can use bitmapData.draw for example. Then you use those bitmaps as sprites for fast rendering. Rendering vectors directly on the gpu does not work too well unfortunately. Flash tried to do this with wmode=gpu, and while it is nice for some demos it never performs at the same quality like rendering in cpu and blitting on the gpu. It is a lot harder to program, but if you really need the performance, for example in a game, it is worth it.